# SetParent() resizing main form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, parent-child, dllimport

I am using `SetParent()` to embed my form on an existing window.
It works fine but when I move the existing window, my form gets resized to existing window's size. So for example if  my form's size is 300x200 and the windows size is 800x800, once I move(drag) the window, my form gets resized to the window's size(800x800).
Is there a way to avoid that?

This is my code:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        public static int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;


        //my call of the methods
        SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE) | WS_CHILD);
        SetParent(this.Handle, GetHandle());
```

Comment: If you turn on the WS_CHILD style flag then the program might think it is actually a child window.  And treat it that way.  Of course it is not so don't turn on that style flag.  As I said, ymmv.

Comment: This (ab)use of `SetParent` doesn't work out. Find a different way.

Comment: @HansPassant I have already tried turning it off. The form still gets resized once the main window moves.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan according to research, this is a good way to embed a form on a window. Do you suggest something else?

Comment: No, it's a really bad idea that doesn't really work and only exists for back compat for code from 16 bit days

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you suggest anything else then? Besides than moving my form everytime the window moves.

Comment: I suggest that you don't mix the UI from two separate processes